# Run with elevated rights fails on WIN7

Tags: delphi, windows-7

I am developing using Delphi 6 on a WinXP system.

I have been using the following function to run a program with elevated rights.

```
function LB_RunAsAdminWait(hWnd:       HWND;
                           filename:   string;
                           Parameters: string): Boolean;
   var   sei: TShellExecuteInfo;                // shell execute info
begin

   Result := False;                             // default to failure

   FillChar(sei, SizeOf(sei), 0);
   sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
   sei.Wnd    := hWnd;
   sei.fMask  := SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
   sei.lpVerb := 'runas';
   sei.lpFile := PChar(filename);
   sei.lpParameters := PChar(Parameters);
   sei.nShow  := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

   if ShellExecuteEx(@sei) then                 // if success
      Result := True;                           //    return sucess

   if sei.hProcess <> 0 then begin              // wait for process to finish
      while WaitForSingleObject(sei.hProcess, 50) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
         Application.ProcessMessages;
      CloseHandle(sei.hProcess);
   end;

end;  // of function LB_RunAsAdminWait
```

How I call it:

```
if (LB_RunAsAdminWait(FPGM.Handle,'RegSvr32',FName+' /s') = False) then
   begin
     ShowMessage('WARNING: unable to register OCX');
     exit;
   end;
```

where FPGM.handle is the handle to my application
and Fname is the OCX i want to register.

When I run it on a WIN7 machine it returns true(successful) but the OCX is not registered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely explanation is that this is a 32 bit vs 64 bit issue. The DLL is 64 bit, and you are running the 32 bit regsvr32. Or vice versa. Or the file system redirector is confounding you. You put the DLL in system32, but the redirector turns that into SysWow64.

The obvious way to debug it is to remove the silent switch and let regsvr32 tell you what went wrong.

As an aside, as you have discovered, you cannot use the return value of ShellExecuteEx to determine whether or not the server registration succeeded. The return value of ShellExecuteEx merely tells you whether or not the process started.

Comment: Thank you. the problem turned out on the 64 bit WIN7 machine the OCX was located in a directory that contained a space in it. If it contained a space the REGSVR32 failed so I put " around the OCX name and it worked unless there was no space then it failed.  I ended up checking the name for a space and if it had one put the quotes around it.  By the way, you are my hero.  Every question I have ever ask on StackOverflow you have given me an answer.  More often that not it has turned out to be the one that solved my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Well thank you! Very nice of you. Although in this case my guess was wrong, but the debugging tip was sound.